# Which implementation of SAXParserFactory is used?

Tags: xml, saxparser

I am dealing with xml pasring. When I check code for SAXParserFactory, I see

```
public static SAXParserFactory newInstance() {
    try {
        return (SAXParserFactory) FactoryFinder.find(
            /* The default property name according to the JAXP spec */
            "javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory",
            /* The fallback implementation class name */
            "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl");
    } catch (FactoryFinder.ConfigurationError e) {
        throw new FactoryConfigurationError(e.getException(),
                                            e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I am wondering which implementation of SAXParserFactory is actually returned? How can I check which implementation am I dealing with? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

As usual in a factory pattern, the SaxParserFactory has its own initialization method. It is well explained in the javadoc of the method (see [SAXParserFactory.newInstance()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParserFactory.html#newInstance())
).

The implementation for the factory is searched as follow:

- first checks if there a system property: sometimes a bad written library set this property but it is rare
- second checks in jaxp.properties: this is a JRE setting but is not the default
- third checks in runtime jars: searching for META-INF/services/javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory; for example in xercexImpl.jar you find this file, it contains this text com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl (this is the factory implementation returned by the method when you have this jar in your runtime env)
- fourth checks for a platform default implementation: I don't know to which platform it refers, maybe a java container (J2EE application server)

If you like to experiment try to start your jvm with -Djaxp.debug=1 (as specified in the javadoc).